# Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/

Tags: eclipse, swt, editor, eclipse-rcp, bundle

I started with a RCP-Plug-in and wrote an own Editor. Running the project I've got this error

"**Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui.internal.handlers.ResetToDefaultHandler**". 
I have the last error message with a lot of other handlers, too, e.g. "AutosizeColumnsHandler", "UnmarkItemsHandler", "RepairDuplicateItemsHandler"...

I've checked with OSGi-console that OSGi can't see my bundle. I don't use e4 modeling in my project.

I'm running my RCP as a product " org.eclipse.sdk.ide".

Does anybody know what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your RCP? `ResetToDefaultHandler` is part of the e4 tools package which is usually installed in your main Eclipse but probably don't want in an RCP.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your reply. I'm running my RCP as a product " org.eclipse.sdk.ide". I have seen under "Run Configurations" -> "Plug-ins" that I have marked many "eclipse.e4.core. ..." and "eclipse.e4.ui. ..." plug-ins. But when I unmark them, I get these errors (see screenshot) and java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found. Do you have any idea?

Comment: With that product id you will need to include pretty much all the plugins.

Comment: @greg-499 Thank you, that could be my problem. I don't know how to do it. Could you please briefly explain?

Comment: Well you have just told us you unmarked things in the Run Configuration - you will have to set them again. On the Plugins tab click 'Add Required Plug-ins'

Comment: @greg-499 Okay thanks. Sorry, but why do I need these Plug-ins when I do not use e4 modeling in my project?

Comment: Because the core of Eclipse is built using EMF

Comment: @greg-499 ah, okay, this explains several thins. I have added "Required Plug-Ins", but I still have these errors: Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui.internal.handlers.MarkDuplicateElementIdsHandler, MarkDuplicateLabelsHandler, MarkDuplicateAttributesHandler, RepairDuplicateItemsHandler, UnmarkItemsHandler, AutosizeColumnsHandler, ResetToDefaultHandler . Do you how can I avoid them?

Comment: At a guess it is still missing some plugins, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run the RCP as an application `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench`. Furthermore "add Required Plug-ins" in the "plug-in" tab in the run configuration did not add the plugin `org.eclipse.equinox.ds`, which was necessary. I added it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's didn't work for me right the way... But i still managed to get it work just fine. Those are the steps i took to make it work:

> 1. Remove the product(if you already have one) from your "run configurations"
> 2. Add a new product for your project. To add a product select the project: "right click" on the project -> "New" -> "others..." ->
>      in wizard write product and select "Product Configurations" and click
>      "next". Select the project if it's not already done. Name your product
>      (usually <>.product), check "Create a configurations
>      file with the basic settings" and dial "Finish". Now you've got a
>      product file. Go to "Overview"(make sure to fill a product ID and the
>      Name. In "Product Definition" under "Product" and "Application" select
>      the product and the application.
> 3. Now move to "Dependencies" and your project under "Add..." and its dependencies under "Add Required Plug-ins".
> 4. You're almost finish yet... Now let get to the trickiest part. For reasons unknown some plug-ins don't get to be picked up by
>      the eclipse auto-analysis, so you need to add them by yourself. Add
>      "org.eclipse.equinox.ds" and "org.eclipse.equinox.event"to your
>      plug-ins dependencies and "Add Required Plug-ins".
> 5. Move back to Overview hit "synchronize" under "Testing" and Launch with "Launch an Eclipse application".

Those steps work pretty fine for me... Now i hope, i helped with my contribution.